# iOS How to add "Done" bar to input keyboard?

Tags: ios

[image]

[image]

Like the two pictures, a self-window bar is above the keyboard. How to make it? Are there any third-party libraries doing it?

Comment: third party library? :) no. you can add it anything directly to your view, e.g. when the keyboard appears... therefore, you can add any bar with e.g. "done" button any time... how do you build up a regular view in your app?

Comment: @holex Thanks but how to code it? Are there any samples? Just move my window to the keyboard?

Comment: you may use the standard `–addSubview:` to add a subview to your view, in the method which called when the keyboard is appearing.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing complicated to it whatsoever. Assign the view you want to appear above the keyboard as the text field or view's [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView) (scroll down to that property; Apple's dodgy approach to HTML doesn't permit deeper links). No need for third-party anything; it's a built-in function of UIKit.

Besides that reference to the class documentation, Apple has [documented this in the abstract](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) and provides [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html).